# What is the correct graphical representation of an empty UML class?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, representation

Most UML tools represent an empty UML class with empty fields for both, attributes and operations. But looking at the UML Infrastructure and Superstructure, there are a lot of empty classes shown as one single rectangle including the name of the class. But I cannot find a clear statement which of both representations is absolutly correct.

**So which graphical representation is correct - both or just one of them - and where is your information coming from?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though @JimL's answer is correct, here is the section from Superstructures 2.5 that explains the use of compartments:

> The model in Figure B.6 specializes UMLDiagramElement and UMLShape
> into UMLCompartmentableShape and UMLCompartment, respectively, to make
> them concrete, add properties, and redefine inherited properties for
> shapes with segregated contents.
>
> UMLCompartmetableShape is the most
> general class for UML elements that may have information shown in
> separated portions inside their shapes, usually arranged linearly and
> separated by solid lines (compartments). It subsets ownedElement from
> UMLDiagramElement to specify compartments that are to appear
> vertically ordered (first in order is shown at the top), where are
> captured with UMLCompartment. UMLCompartment subsets ownedElement from
> UMLDiagramElement to specify contents of compartments that are to
> appear vertically ordered (first in order is shown at the top).
> UMLCompartments have no modelElements.
>
> Compartment titles shall be
> interchanged as UMLLabels with no modelElements, and as the first
> orderedElement of UMLCompartments.
>
> [image]

It means that you can show from zero to `N` compartments.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. Showing compartments is optional.